# What's does "Mastwurf - gesteckt" mean when talking about climbing knots?

Tags: translation, vocabulary, technical-terminology

I'm translating this term for a video. It seems to refer to a [clove hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clove_hitch), but I'm having a little trouble working out what the "gesteckt" stands for.

Comment: If I would be someone with knowledge in "knoting" I would know what the corresponding wiki article is talking about = which part of the english article refers to gesteckt: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webeleinenstek . Yes, Mastwurf is s clove hitch. And it is said to be a very well known one.

Comment: I mean, did you even try to plug the term into google? Which part of the first result ([an instruction with images](http://www.outdoorfreunde.net/knoten/mastwurf-gesteckt)) was it that didn't satisfy your curiosity? ;-)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: now that we've explained it everyone here knows what 'gesteckt' means and how it fits in with other methods. But I didn't know before I actually had to learn and use it, and I wouldn't expect climbers to learn those details. And even if, I wouldn't expect them to correctly translate it into a language that I believe doesn't have a nautical term (to commandeer :-)) for it. I may be wrong, tho.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Clove hitch" is correct, in German also known as "Weblein-" or "Webeleinenstek".

English doesn't distinguish between "werfen" and "stecken", afaik. These are just two methods of tying the knot. In boating, "stecken" means tying by hand, "werfen" means you take the end (that's the rope anywhere along its length) in two loops and throw them over the bitt. The latter needs some practice, but is the easiest and quickest way to get a land connection single handed (boating-wise, I mean).

Look at the [link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webeleinenstek) @ShegitBrahm provided, under "Festmachen am Pfahl", the [first](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webeleinenstek#/media/Datei:Mastwurf_Binden.jpg) depiction shows how to "stecken", the [last](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webeleinenstek#/media/Datei:Mastwurf_Legen.jpg) one how to "werfen" the knot.

Comment: A "thrown" knot does not need to be thrown at all. The difference is that a thrown not can be put on the "to-be-tied"-object after doing the knot. "sticking" means you have to built the knot around the object, as there is no open end to "throw" it over (as the bitt in boating). This is the more prevalent way for knots, as you can tie it around a rail/ladder/tree/whatever. It is more universal but not as quick/easy to do.

Comment: Depending on circumstances and skill it can gently be laid with two fingers, cool be thrown to show-off in front of the marina café, pushed over a pilling with a boat hook while balancing on one leg and holding on to a stay, only to end up in the water and blocking the propeller. Yeah, there are a lot of ways and methods, other knots are better suited. And if the rope is sticky you can just try and rely on its adhesive forces :-) But that doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that "geworfen" sometimes is also called "gelegt" and has a more narrow use case than "gesteckt".

Answer (score 9):

There are two fundamentally different ways to tie a clove hitch:

1. "gesteckt", using the end of the rope, see Method 1 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs9WyrzNjJs). For this method, you don't have to access the end of the pole you're tying the rope to. In general, "(einen Knoten) stecken" means tying a knot step by step (i.e. statically) using the end of the rope.
2. "geworfen", using the middle of the rope on the end of the pole, see Method 2 in [the same video](https://youtu.be/Gs9WyrzNjJs?t=32). For that method, you don't need the end of the rope. In general, "(einen Knoten) werfen" means tying a knot dynamically in few steps, using the rope's kinetics (i.e. inertia and stiffness).

Comment: just a minor remark: there is no video linked in the question. Maybe you are referring to a link given in a comment below the question?

Comment: Thanks! Hm, the video is not in the edit history of the question either... might indeed have been in a deleted comment.
I've simply removed the reference, since linking another clove hitch video would be somewhat redundant by itself.